# If a $3\times 4$ matrix has $(2,3,1,0)$ spanning its null space, find the $RREF$ of the matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I know that the rank of the matrix must be $3$, since there is exactly one free variable (since exactly one vector spans the null space).

But I am not sure how to reconstruct the exact $RREF$ that would have this vector spanning its null space. All I know is that the last column would be a free variable, and that the other three columns would be linearly independent, since again there is only one variable in the basis of the null space.

I actually would not even think that it is possible to get the $RREF$ with just this information. We can know that $2\times$column$1$ $+ 3 \times $column$2$ $+$column$3$ equals $0$ for all three rows, but how does that uniquely determine a matrix?

Comment: Here's a hint: Since the rank is $3$, there must be $3$ pivot columns and $1$ non-pivot column. Where should they be and what should they look like?

Comment: If you need more hint: Write down *any arbitrary* $4\times 3$ (or really, $3\times 4$?) RREF matrix with rank $3$, and solve for its null space. Then meditate on the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that the null space and row space of the matrix are orthogonal complements. So $v=[x,y,z,w]^T$ is a vector in the row-space of the matrix iff$$\langle[2,3,1,0]^T,v\rangle=0\iff 2x+3y+z=0\\v=[x,y,z,w]^T=x[1,0,-2,0]^T+y[0,1,-3,0]^T+w[0,0,0,1]^T$$We want to select three linearly independent row vectors so one possible option is$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-2&0\\0&1&-3&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$Note that we cannot determine the matrix uniquely. We may change the order of the row vectors or take some other linearly independent vectors in the row-space and row-reduce the matrix to obtain another valid choice.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't think about how the row space is the complement of the null space. Can you expand on the line where you said $v=[x,y,z,w]^T=x[1,0,-2,0]^T+y[0,1,-3,0]^T+w[0,0,0,1]^T$? I am not completely sure how to get those vectors, or how did you know to not use $z$

Comment: @ZackHelms I substituted $z=-2x-3y$ in $[x,y,z,w]^T$.